# Angular (Typescript) Unit Testing - ASP.Net Core MVC SPA

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, chutzpah

I am developing a project which started life as an ASP.Net Core MVC SPA Template in Visual Studio 2015. I used the Visual Studio Karma Test Adapter with no problems for my Angular (Typescript) unit testing, but no matter what I tried I could not get NUnit to recognise my C# unit tests for the Web API and early Domain Model code. I tried to add a separate Test Project with no success and I also created unit test files within the same, single, project with no success.

At some point I knew I should migrate the code to Visual Studio 2017, as I feel that the new IDE will prove to be beneficial as the project develops, so I thought I would do it now and see if it solves my unit testing problems. Visual Studio's migration process didn't go well so I decided to start from scratch again.

I ran `dotnet new angular` to create a clean solution which I opened in VS 2017. It appears that the Visual Studio Karma Test Adapter does not work with VS 2017 yet, so for the Typescript (Jasmine) testing that left me with Chutzpah. No matter what I try I cannot write the simplest of Jasmine tests and have the Visual Studio Test Explorer recognise it (let alone run the test). I haven't even begun to look at the C# Unit Testing yet.

Can anyone else get a Jasmine Unit Test to be recognised and run in the VS Test Explorer from a clean `dotnet new angular` solution, I would be very grateful for some advise.